# Request to reopen a closed-as-duplicate question: Can you write "... me's" (the possessive)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicates

**Note**: The question has now been reopened. I have added further examples of the group genitive to my answer to the question. This should help to distinguish it further from the hyphenated compound nouns question.

---

The following question

[Can you write "... me's" (the possessive)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611169/can-you-write-mes-the-possessive)

was closed as a duplicate of

[How to indicate possession by e.g. passers-by, mothers-in-law](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/how-to-indicate-possession-by-e-g-passers-by-mothers-in-law)

The two question titles alone should be enough evidence that the questions are asking for different information. In the first, the OP is asking about the grammaticality of a possessive phrase ending with "me's" (*The person behind me's...*).

And in the second the OP is asking how to write the genitive form of hyphenated plural noun compounds such as *passers-by* and *mothers-in-law*.

The most highly upvoted answer in the "*passers-by*" question starts: *"Mothers-in-law's" is a correct form. I am quoting the rule used in American grammar.* And is simply followed by a blockquote of the rule whose first sentence is "*Also add an apostrophe followed by an s to the end of a singular compound noun that ends in any letter except s"*. (No source for the rule is given.)

It is not clear to me how site visitors interested in reading an answer to the "*The person behind me's...*" question are helped by redirecting them to the only marginally duplicate "*passers-by*" question.

Comment: I really think it is a duplicate, but the question it's a duplicate of seems to have vanished, even after I searched ELL too (or more likely, I'm misremembering it being more related than it is). While I was searching for this mythical duplicate, I did not find any other duplicates that looked like a good fit.